# I want to have the choice for 2 variations with one product in Django

Tags: django

Hi I have Product model , ProductColor and Product Size model. I want to link product with size and color properly, For eg my user when they select say Small size for A prouct(Tshrit) it should shows only available color for that small size.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    active =models.BooleanField(default=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class ProductColor(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.color

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return self.product.get_absolute_url()
```

## product Size

```
CHOOSE_SIZE = (
('Extra Small', 'XS'),
('Small', 'S'),
('Medium', 'M'),
('Large', 'L'),
('Extra Large', 'XL'),
('Double Large', 'XXL'),
('Triple Large', 'XXXL'),
)
```

## variation for product to choose size

```
class ProductSize(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=CHOOSE_SIZE)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.size

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return self.product.get_absolute_url()
```

## product detail Html page

```
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h3>{{ object.price }}</h3>
            <!-- <select class="form-control">
                {% for vari_obj in object.productsize_set.all %}
                    <option value="{{ vari_obj.id }}">{{ vari_obj }}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
                 </select> -->
        {% if object.variation_set.count > 1 %}
            <h5>Size</h5>
                <select class="form-control">
                {% for vari_obj in object.productsize_set.all %}
                    <option value="{{ vari_obj.id }}">{{ vari_obj }}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
                 </select>
        {% endif %}
        <br/>
        <h5>Available Color</h5>
             <select class="form-control">
                {% for color_obj in object.productcolor_set.all %}
                    <option value="{{ color_obj.id }}">{{ color_obj }}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
    <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
</div><!--end of col-sm-4!-->
```

Thank You the current situation problem is since I have not linked product size and color properly, when I add Red Shirt Large, Red shirt Small and Blue color shirt Medium for the same product. On my Product detial page Dropdwon for avaialble color size is follow :Red,Red,Blue

Comment: What do you want? What did you try? What did you expect?

Comment: I am making website for clothing store and I want to have option for Selcting Size and Color for the given product and show only available color for the Size of the products.
I Tried the above mention method and Ididnot expect anything as I know that there is no link between size and color model. Only my product model is link with color and size.

I want to know how to link those two model , ProductCOlor and ProductSize for the given product.

Comment: If your product as only one size and one color, you can use OneToOneField to link the 3 models.

Comment: My product will have size (from xs-xxxL) and regarding color it will be different and may vary product to product.

Answer (score 1):

create a new model named ProductSizeColor like this

```
class ProductSizeColor(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    color = models.ForeignKey(ProductColor)
    size = models.ForeignKey(ProductSize)
```

now when you are inserting all data into table just insert product, color and size into ProductSizeColor model. If you need all color for XL size tom t shirt, search like this

```
ProductSizeColor.objects.filter(
    product=tom_t_shirt_object,
    size=XL_size_object_for_tom_t_shirt
)
```

Comment: Nop its not working.The general idea is to have "ProductColor" for each ProductSize and therefore I can show those ProductColor if they exist in the database. I guess  I may need  many to many field relationship, I am new to Django and facing problem. Anyway thanks for the help